# Show only number in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a data in my database, which contains number and text both like [ **4,First Appeal** ].Now fetch the data and want to show only the **TEXT** not the **NUMBER** part.How can I do

```
<tr>
   <td><strong>Case type :</strong>{{ $case_details->case_type }}</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on a string if it is always going to be comma separated. I would probably add some checking as the `[0]` could fail if there is no comma in the data. Secondly, I would suggest you revaluate how you are storing your data as it seems like this structure is not very efficient for multiple reasons. One suggestion would be be to only refer type to a number which has a config on the server which has the corresponding `First Appeal` or maybe a separate table of types with a foreign key to the types on `case_details`.

```
<tr>
   <td><strong>Case type :</strong>{{ explode(",", $case_details->case_type)[0] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Rifat you can accept my answer for further readers if it was helpful :)